# How to extract performance metrics measured by measureBlock in XCTest

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

I have a simple test function which will tap a button an measure the performance. I'm using XCTest. After measureBlock returns I can see a bunch of perf-metrics on the console. I would like to get this within the test-program such that I can populate the data somewhere else programmatically. Watching the test data on test-console is proving to be slow because I have a lot of test-cases.

```
- (void)testUseMeasureBlock {
    XCUIElement *launchTest1Button = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init].buttons[@"Launch Test 1"];
    void (^blockToMeasure)(void) = ^void(void) {
        [launchTest1Button tap];
    };
    // Run once to warm up any potential caching properties
    @autoreleasepool {
        blockToMeasure();
    }

    // Now measure the block
    [self measureBlock:blockToMeasure];
    /// Collect the measured metrics and send somewhere.
```

When we run a test it prints:

```
measured [Time, seconds] average: 0.594, relative standard deviation: 0.517%, values: [0.602709, 0.593631, 0.593004, 0.592350, 0.596199, 0.593807, 0.591444, 0.593460, 0.592648, 0.592769],
```

If I could get the average time, that'd be sufficient for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a private instance variable `__perfMetricsForID` of `XCTestCase` store the result.
And you can access it by call

```
 NSDictionary* perfMetrics = [testCase valueForKey:@"__perfMetricsForID"];
```

the result is just like this:[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no API to get this data you can pipe `stderr` stream and parse tests logs to get needed info e.g. average time. For instance you can use next approach:

```c
@interface MeasureParser : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSPipe* pipe;
@property (nonatomic) NSRegularExpression* regex;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary* results;

@end

@implementation MeasureParser

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super self];
    if (self) {
        self.pipe = NSPipe.pipe;
        self.results = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        
        let pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[^']+'\\S+\\s([^\\]]+)\\]'\\smeasured\\s\\[Time,\\sseconds\\]\\saverage:\\s([^,]+)"];
        NSError* error = nil;
        self.regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
        if (error) {
            return nil;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)capture:(void (^)(void))block {
    // Save original output
    int original = dup(STDERR_FILENO);

    setvbuf(stderr, nil, _IONBF, 0);
    dup2(self.pipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor, STDERR_FILENO);
    
    __weak let wself = self;
    self.pipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = ^(NSFileHandle *handle) {
        var *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:handle.availableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        
        let firstMatch = [wself.regex firstMatchInString:str options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
        if (firstMatch) {
            let name = [str substringWithRange:[firstMatch rangeAtIndex:1]];
            let average = [str substringWithRange:[firstMatch rangeAtIndex:2]];
            wself.results[name] = average;
        }
        
        // Print to stdout because stderr is piped
        printf("%s", [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    };
    
    block();
    
    // Revert
    fflush(stderr);
    dup2(original, STDERR_FILENO);
    close(original);
}

@end
```

How to use:

```c
- (void)testPerformanceExample {
    
    let measureParser = [MeasureParser new];
    
    [measureParser capture:^{
        [self measureBlock:^{
            // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
            sleep(1);
        }];
    }];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", measureParser.results);
}

// Outputs

{
    testPerformanceExample = "1.001";
}
```

Comment: You mixed Objective-C with Swift :D There is no let or var in Objc :)

Comment: @WezSieTato It's ObjC, `let` and `var` are macroses with `__auto_type`: #define let __auto_type const, #define var __auto_type that are useful to eliminate type declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 version

```
final class MeasureParser {
    let pipe: Pipe = Pipe()
    let regex: NSRegularExpression?
    let results: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

    init() {
        self.regex = try? NSRegularExpression(
            pattern: "\\[(Clock Monotonic Time|CPU Time|Memory Peak Physical|Memory Physical|CPU Instructions Retired|Disk Logical Writes|CPU Cycles), (s|kB|kI|kC)\\] average: ([0-9\\.]*),",
            options: .caseInsensitive)
    }

    func capture(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let original = dup(STDERR_FILENO)
        setvbuf(stderr, nil, _IONBF, 0)
        dup2(self.pipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor, STDERR_FILENO)

        self.pipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { [weak self] handle  in
            guard self != nil else { return }
            let data = handle.availableData
            let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "<Non-ascii data of size\(data.count)>\n"
            self!.fetchAndSaveMetrics(str)

            // Print to stdout because stderr is piped
            if let copy = (str as NSString?)?.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                print("\(copy)")
            }
        }
        completion()
        fflush(stderr)
        dup2(original, STDERR_FILENO)
        close(original)
    }

    private func fetchAndSaveMetrics(_ str: String) {
        guard let mRegex = self.regex else { return }
        let matches = mRegex.matches(in: str, options: .reportCompletion, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.count))
        matches.forEach {
            let nameIndex = Range($0.range(at: 1), in: str)
            let averageIndex = Range($0.range(at: 3), in: str)
            if nameIndex != nil && averageIndex != nil {
                let name = str[nameIndex!]
                let average = str[averageIndex!]
                self.results[name] = average
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
import XCTest

final class MyUiTests: XCTestCase {

    var app: XCUIApplication!
    let measureParser = MeasureParser()

    // MARK: - XCTestCase

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
        app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        //FIXME: Just for debugging
        print(self.measureParser.results)
        print(self.measureParser.results["CPU Cycles"])
        print(self.measureParser.results["CPU Instructions Retired"])
        print(self.measureParser.results["CPU Time"])
        print(self.measureParser.results["Clock Monotonic Time"])
        print(self.measureParser.results["Disk Logical Writes"])
        print(self.measureParser.results["Memory Peak Physical"])
        print(self.measureParser.results["Memory Physical"])
    }

    // MARK: - Tests

    func testListing() {
        self.measureParser.capture { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.measureListingScroll()
        }
    }

    // MARK: XCTest measures

    private func measureListingScroll() {
        measure(metrics: [XCTCPUMetric(), XCTClockMetric(), XCTMemoryMetric(), XCTStorageMetric()]) {
            self.app.swipeUp()
            self.app.swipeUp()
            self.app.swipeUp()
        }
    }
}
```